# Response Surface Methodology-Third Order

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use RSM and calculate 3rd order polynomials.for quadratic below is given in Matlab Help:

stats = regstats(rsmOutput,rsmMatrix,'quadratic','beta');

b = stats.beta; % Model coefficients

How can I calculate 3rd order coefficients? My reason is that with quadratic I have rsquare of 93% and my observed responses is third order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        modelMatrix = [0 0 0;
            1 0 0;
            0 1 0;
            0 0 1;
            1 1 0;
            1 0 1;
            0 1 1;
            2 0 0;
            0 2 0;
            0 0 2;
            1 1 1;
            2 1 0;
            2 0 1;
            1 2 0;
            1 0 2;
            0 2 1;
            3 0 0;
            0 3 0;
            0 0 3];
           stats = regstats(rsmOutput,rsmMatrix,modelMatrix,'beta');
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
stats = regstats(y,X,model,whichstats)
```

the 'model' can be a matrix of model terms accepted by the 'x2fx' function. See [x2fx](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/x2fx.html) for a description of this matrix and for a description of the order in which terms appear. You can use this matrix to specify other models including ones without a constant term.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but I am still not sure how to do this in matlab. model parameter can be at most 'quadratic', but in my case I want cubic polynomials

Comment: The link for x2fx explains it pretty well: for high-order terms you have to specify a matrix, instead of 'quadratic', etc.

Comment: 3rd order polynomials are given herehttp://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri336.htm